# Weird crash when creating menu

Tags: java, android, menu, crash

I'm changing things around inside of my `onCreateOptionsMenu` and I'm getting a really weird crash. **Logcat** tells me it crashed:

This is the crash :

```
at com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
```

And that it's a null pointer exception.

Here's my `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
        @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, menu);

    MenuItem shareNew = menu.findItem(R.id.shareNew);
    MenuItem shareOld = menu.findItem(R.id.shareOld);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) shareNew.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        shareOld.setVisible(true);
        shareNew.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        shareOld.setVisible(false);
        shareNew.setVisible(true);
    }

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search articles");

    setupSearchView(searchItem);

    return true;

}
```

And here's my `main_menu.xml`:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/starred"
    android:title="Starred articles"    />

<item
    android:queryHint="Search articles"
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />


<item

    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:id="@+id/shareNew"
    android:title="Share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"/>



<item

    android:id="@+id/shareOld"
    android:title="Share"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/star"
    android:title="Star article"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/star"   />

<item
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh"    
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"   />

<item
    android:id="@+id/forward"
    android:title="Forward"
    android:icon="@drawable/forward"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"   />

<item
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/copy"
    android:id="@+id/copy"
    android:title="Copy url"    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/browser"
    android:title="Open in browser" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/startPage"
    android:title="Use as startpage"    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/random"
    android:title="Random article"  />

<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="Settings"    />
```

Help would be really appreaciated (and needed :p)

Comment: Doesn't logcat tell you a line number at which the exception occurs?

Comment: I think you should post the error log here

Comment: You've shown which file the exception occurs in - but not what the exception is, or whether there were any line numbers for your code. Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Is there a difference between the stack trace and the normal logcat error log? I dont really know how to get the stack trace. By the way I wrote that it's a nullPointerException.

Comment: @SweSnow Can you please post the logcat including 10line above your exception and 10 lines below your exception. It has valuable information. Just posting a line with exception is not enough.

Comment: @SweSnow: Ah, I'd missed that - because it wasn't where I'd expected it to be - at the start of the exception. The full stack trace would include that. If your stack trace really doesn't include the line number in your code, try enabling debug options so you can find out where it is. Or heck, just running it in a debugger should show you...

Comment: Hang on - I wouldn't even expect the code you've provided to compile. You've declared `shareNew` at the "top level" of the method, and *also* within `if` blocks. Is this a modified version of your code somehow?

Comment: @Jon Skeet this isn't modified at all. Removed the part where I declared shareNew and shareOld from the if and else and kept the one at the top but theres no diffrence. I'll post some more of the stack trace when I get home

Comment: @SweSnow: If that's not modified, then I fail to see how it compiles in the first place - so either you're not actually *running* the code you've got, or my view of the world is shot. (It's not clear *why* you were fetching them in the `if` block anyway, mind you....)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'm not at home yet so I cant post the entire but I looked through it just now on my phone (logcat app) and everything above and under the onCreateOptionsMenu looks exactly like all other crashes I've ever got that are null pointer exceptions. Would you like me to post the entire activity on pastebin maybe?

Comment: @SweSnow: Ideally I'd like you to create a short but complete example which *only* shows this issue, and edit it into the question instead of putting it on an external site.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I don't really know what part shows the issue except for the 'onCreateOptionsMenu' so I just updated it for now. Is there a specific part that could be important?

Comment: @SweSnow: Well that's for you to diagnose... you haven't told us anything about what you've tried in order to diagnose this - adding log statements, stepping through it in the debugger etc.